# Inverse image is contained in the inverse image of the closure.

Tags: general-topology

Let (X, T ),(Y, T1 ) be topological spaces and f : (Y, T1 ) → (X, T ) a continuous map. Let A ⊆ X.
Show that f−1(A) ⊆ f−1(A). 
Give an example where the reverse inequality is not true.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Are you asking whether a set is subset of itself? You probably mean something else..

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{f^{-1}[A]} \subseteq f^{-1}[\overline{A}]$ is true because the right hand set is closed by continuity (inverse image of a closed set) and contains $f^{-1}[A]$ trivially. So the closure of $f^{-1}[A]$ is a subset of  $f^{-1}[\overline{A}]$, as this closure is the *smallest* closed set containing $f^{-1}[A]$.

Take the topology on $X$ to be discrete and on $Y=X$ another non-discrete topology and $f$ the identity to make examples of this being a proper inclusion.